# How to convert exported vtk image to numpy array?

Tags: python, bigdata, visualization, vtk, paraview

Here's the code:

'''

```
import vtk
import numpy as np
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy

# Load the data
reader = vtk.vtkXMLImageDataReader()
reader.SetFileName("Isabel_2D.vti")
reader.Update()
imageData = reader.GetOutput() #read data


# Export the data to a buffer
exporter = vtk.vtkImageExport()
exporter.SetInputData(imageData)
exporter.Update()
data_pointer = exporter.GetPointerToData().GetScalars()

# Get the image data as a numpy array
#imageDataArray = np.frombuffer(data_pointer, np.float32) #.encode()
#imageDataArray = imageDataArray.reshape(imageData.GetDimensions())
rows, cols, _ = exporter.GetDimensions()
imageDataArray = vtk_to_numpy(sc)
imageDataArray = imageDataArray.reshape(rows, cols, -1)
```

'''

How to resolve the following error :

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'GetScalars'

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `exporter` part.

You should get the desired array from the `imageData` (`GetPointData().GetScalars()`) and wrap it. See this same [post](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/ow-to-convert-vtkimagedata-to-numpy-for-a-rgb-image/2387) on vtk forum.